# jQuery Multiple ID selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a snippet of the start of my code:

```
var myUpload = $("#upload_link").upload({bla bla bla
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is make the same call with a few different ID's...

I would have assumed this would work but it doesn't:

```
var myUpload = $("#upload_link,#upload_link2,#upload_link3").upload({
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the upload plugin you are using? Are you sure it follows the recommended plugin development pattern?

Comment: It should work, must be something with the `upload` function. http://jsfiddle.net/X7TAX/

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#upload_link,#upload_link2,#upload_link3").each(function(){
    $(this).upload({
        //whateveryouwant
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer will definitely work but ideally any plugin logic should apply to all the matched elements.

Comment: Is there any way to select like this $('#upload_*')   ?

Comment: @HamidShoja $("*[id^='upload_']") should create an array with all elements starting with 'upload_'

Answer (score 44):

If you give each of these instances a class you can use

```
$('.yourClass').upload()
```

Answer (score 37):

You *can* use multiple `id`'s the way you wrote:

```
$('#upload_link, #upload_link2, #upload_link3')
```

However, that doesn't mean that those ids exist within the DOM when you've executed your code. It also doesn't mean that `upload` is a legitimate function. It also doesn't mean that `upload` has been built in a way that allows for multiple elements in a selection.

`upload` is a custom jQuery plugin, so you'll have to show what's going on with `upload` for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure `upload` plugin implements `this.each` in it so that it will execute the logic for all the matching elements. It should ideally work

```
$("#upload_link,#upload_link2,#upload_link3").upload(function(){ });
```

Answer (score 6):

If all your elements starting with `upload_` in its `id` have the same purpose or syntax you could try and use the following:

```
$("*[id^='upload_']").each(function() {
    $(this).upload()
});
```

This way you don't have to specify every single element in the selector.

Answer (score 5):

it should.  Typically that's how you do multiple selectors.  Otherwise it may not like you trying to assign the return values of three uploads to the same var.

I would suggest using `.each` or maybe push the returns to an array rather than assigning them to that value.

Answer (score 1):

That should work, you may need a space after the commas.

Also, the function you call afterwards must support an array of objects, and not just a singleton object.