# Combine jQuery object with new selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you do a similar function as rsplak's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7079032/1330629 but include a defined variable in this? For example, I have a variable defined so that I'm not querying the DOM repeatedly, such as: `var $StartDateTime = $("#StartDateTime");`

and would like to include it with another selector, which I haven't defined as a variable.

Is this possible? I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
$($StartDateTime,link,#upload_link2,#upload_link3").each(function(){
    $(this).upload({
        //whateveryouwant
    });
});
```

But obviously that's not going to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `add`:

```
var $combined = $('#newElement').add($StartDateTime);
```

Or this overload:

```
var $combined = $StartDateTime.add('#newElement');
```

[`add` docs:](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Description: Add elements to the set of matched elements.

Comment: Does this method allow you to "add" more variables, meaning is it possible to combine more than two variables into one?

Comment: @ouija. You can use this: `$StartDateTime.add('#newElement, #second, #third, #fourth');` There are other ways, but what's wrong with this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work under IE9 or Firefox; I'm using it to set multiple variables in conjunction with jQuery .datetimepicker and two separate input fields, and it doesn't seem to work when I define them in a variable like this, but works when defining the selector(s) themselves and not with the variable...

Comment: @ouija. It should work in any browser, you're doing something wrong, can you reproduce the problem at http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

Either use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) as @gdoron suggested

```
var $combined = $StartDateTime.add('#newElement');
```

Or (IMHO producing a more elegant code) [`jQuery.merge`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/):

```
var $newElement = $('#newElement');
var $combined = $.merge($StartDateTime, $newElement);
```