# jQuery, same function for multiple ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to clear specified input if the value is not number. function works for one ID, but i want it to work for multiple. of course i can write function multiple times but i dont want to do that.

the following code gets effect only for input with id "d". i dont know how to identify other ids. can anyone help?

```
<input id="d" />

<input id="d2" />

<input id="d3" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#d,d2,d3').keyup(function(){

if($('#d,d2,d3').val() != "") {

    var value = $('#d,d2,d3').val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;

    if(intRegex.test(value)) {}

    else {


    $(this).val('');

    }



}

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Instead of `$('#d,d2,d3')` use `$('#d, #d2, #d3')` and for the if statement use `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 9):

You can use **starts with** selector instead of putting in multiple ids like this:

```
$('[id^=d]')
```

Above selector will work for all elements whose ids start with `d` eg `d1`, `d2`, `d3` and so on.

Here is how your code should be (fixing other errors as well):

```
$('[id^=d]').keyup(function(){   
 if(this.value != "") {
    var value = this.value.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    if(intRegex.test(value)) {}
    else {
      this.value = '';
    }
 }    
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question ...! Awsome!

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[id^=d]').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim( this.value ); // or $.trim( $(this).val() )
    if (val != "") {
        var value = val.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''),
            intRegex = /^\d+$/;
            if (intRegex.test(value)) {
                // do something
            } else {
                $(this).val('');
            }
    }
});​
```

`[id^=d]` is a start with selector that means, `id` start with `d`.

Read about **[jQuery start selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `#` for `d2 & d3`. And also a `this`.

```
$('#d,#d2,#d3').keyup(function(){

    if($(this).val() != "") {

        var value = $(this).val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

        var intRegex = /^\d+$/;

        if(intRegex.test(value)) {}
        else {
            $(this).val('');

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the hash for the other two Ids:

```
$('#d,#d2,#d3')
```

see also 
[jQuery Multiple ID selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079011/jquery-multiple-id-selectors)

Answer (score 3):

You can add class attribute

```
   <input id="d" class="A"/> 
    <input id="d2" class="A"/> 
    <input id="d3" class="A"/>
```

use following selector by class name

```
$('.A').keyup
```