# Two element call for one function in one line

Tags: javascript

I have two `Buttons` like this:

```
var btn1 = $("#myButton1");
var btn2 = $("#myButton2");
```

Then I disable those `Buttons`:

```
btn1.prop('disabled', true);
btn2.prop('disabled', true);
```

I tried to make a fast way by calling function like this:

```
$(btn1, btn2).prop('disabled', true); //just btn1 have prop assign
//or
[btn1, btn2].prop('disabled', true); //error here
```

How can I disable the `Buttons` like this (i.e., without an error or a missing assign)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery, same function for multiple ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151157/jquery-same-function-for-multiple-ids)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to achieve this:

```
$("#myButton1, #myButton2").prop("disabled", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
$("#btn1, #btn2").prop('disabled', true);
```

Look at the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in document order.

Answer (score 0):

[According the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) you must comma-seperate the elements like this;

```
$("#myButton1, #myButton2").prop('disabled', true);
```

Or you can wrap the buttons in a `span` or `div` and use the following (*given #myButton1 and #myButton2 are button elements*);

```
$("#mySpan button").prop("disabled", true);
```