# How to add more than document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following is working fine:

```
document.getElementById("comment").style.background=color
```

I'd like to add several IDs. The following do not work:

```
document.getElementById("comment, name, url").style.background=color
document.querySelectorAll("comment, name, url").style.background=color
```

Can someone suggest what code avoiding to write a new function to bind all the ids?

EDIT:
This is the code I am working on:
On the header I have:

```
<script>
function setbg(color)
{
document.getElementById("comment").style.background=color
}
</script>
```

And it styles well the following textarea:

```
<p><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4" required="" title="Mandatory field" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');" onblur="setbg('white')" placeholder="Add a comment here..." style="background-color: white; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></textarea></p>
```

But I'd like it to work also for:

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="" size="22" tabindex="3" placeholder="WWW" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');" onblur="setbg('white')">
```

As well as per other fields, like email, name, etc.

Comment: Where do you use jquery ? $("#comment, #name, #url").css('background-color', color); should work.

Comment: Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079011/jquery-multiple-id-selectors

Comment: JavaScript works on *HTML*, not *PHP* (please show the HTML created by that PHP, 'view source' in your browser).

Comment: Ok, I put clean html now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create, and use, a function:

```
function colorElement(id, color){
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
}

colorElement('comment', 'red');
colorElement('name', 'green');
colorElement('url', 'blue');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gKgty/).

Or you can use an array of element `id`s:

```
['comment', 'name', 'url'].forEach(function(a){
    document.getElementById(a).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gKgty/1/).

Or, as a development of the previous (which allows you to set different colours):

```
[{
    "id": "comment",
    "color": "red"
}, {
    "id": "name",
    "color": "green"
}, {
    "id": "url",
    "color": "blue"
}].forEach(function (a) {
    document.getElementById(a.id).style.backgroundColor = a.color;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gKgty/2/).

Comment: I believe you meant `colorElement()` instead of `color()`?

Comment: I did; just caught that when I was writing the demo. Thanks! =D

Comment: Hmm, thanks. But I don't need to specify the color on the header. I will specify it on the different forms... for example: `onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');"`.Now I am using in the header `<script>
function setbg(color)
{
document.getElementById("comment").style.background=color
}
</script>`, but I'd like the color to be set later via `setbg`

Comment: I honestly aren't sure quite what you're asking (incidentally, you don't seem to be using jQuery from what you've written/shown, why is it in the tags?); do you want to change the `background-color` of a given element (`form`?) when one of its children is focused? Or change the colour of a form control (`input`, `textarea`...)?

Comment: Hmm... I found this tutorial on a site. It was called  "Style textaread with HTML5 + jQuery". I thought it is jQuery, but I have no idea. Please take a look here [Link text](http://glamourina.pl/chicspicy-dress/) ... Now the code works only for the textarea. I'd like to work for all the other fields

Comment: I have no idea where you *meant* to send me, but I don't think it was *that* site (which features many pictures of an attractive woman, which is not unwelcome, but it certainly doesn't seem to mention jQuery or HTML5). Please, post the minimal ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) code (HTML and JavaScript/jQuery) in your question, where we can *see* what you're trying to do. Ideally *also* publish a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can play, and experiment, with it.

Comment: My apologies. The site I sent you, is the site where I am trying to apply the code. The site where there is written this is jQuery is here [link](http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-nice-textarea/)

Comment: No problem with that; though I'd still be interested in seeing the relevant (as mentioned before) simple/minimal code you're working with (added to your question), and a clear explicit statement of what you're trying to do, and what's going wrong with your attempt(s). That way we can more easily, and specifically, help you out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged jQuery, here's a way:

```
$("#comment, #name, #url").css("background-color",color);
```

This grabs multiple ids, and applies the style to them.

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementById` method can only get one element, so you would need to use it on each id:

```
var ids = ["comment", "name", "url"];
for (i in ids) {
  document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.background = color;
}
```

The `querySelectorAll` takes a selector, so you would need to prefix each id with `#`, then you need to loop through the result as you can only set a property on one element at a time:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll("#comment, #name, #url");
for (i in el) {
  el[i].style.background = color;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/B3J4a/

Comment: `for..in` over an _Array_?

Comment: @PaulS.: It iterates of the keys, and the keys in an array is the indexes.

Comment: I've tried both of them, but in my code don't work :(
Probably I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Pikk: I added a link to a demo.

Comment: @Guffa If the browser supports `for..in` but not enumerability, it may also iterate over `length`, similarly if any enumerable keys were added that are non-numeric they will be included even though they're not "items". It's usually better to iterate an _Array_ by using an integer variable. One more thing; you forgot to `var` it so your code currently makes `i` global.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is create an array of ID's and loop over array

```
var els=["comment", "name", "url"];

while (els.length){
  document.getElementById(els.pop()).style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can iterate with array of element name like

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) 
{
   document.getElementById(array[i]).style.background=color;
}
```