# Select several id (select tag) value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select multiple id according to their value (select tag) with jquery.

```html
<select id="year">
    <option value="1900">
</select>

<select id="year2">
   <option value="1950">
</select>
```

I tried several solutions with querySelectorAll, it does not work

Comment: Not so clear what exactly you are trying to select

Comment: I guess dulicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079011/jquery-multiple-id-selectors

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same way you'd do it in a CSS rule:

```
$("#year, #year2").whatever();
```

You can in general separate distinct CSS selectors by commas, meaning that you want the aggregate of what's matched by each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select only the `select` elements that have `value == 1950` for example, you can use the `filter` function:

```js
selected = $('select').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() == 1950;
});
selected.css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="year">
<Option value = "1900">1900</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="year2">
<option value = "1950">1950</option>
</select>
```