# Use the same javascript function for multiple controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use the same JavaScript function for two or more controls.

Is this possible and how?

this is my example:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          showOtherMonths: true,
          selectOtherMonths: true
      });
  });
```

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker2">
```

Comment: Why are you tagging the question with **c#** and **asp.net**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Multiple ID selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079011/jquery-multiple-id-selectors)

Comment: So use a selector that selects more than one element.... Read jQuery's docs on selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class selector instead of id selector and things should be good.

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $(".selectorname").datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true
   });
});

<input type="text" class="selectorname">
<input type="text" class="selectorname">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your selector to the [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) so all the equal classes get affected by the function

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      $(".datepicker").datepicker({
          showOtherMonths: true,
          selectOtherMonths: true
      });
  });

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a multiple id selector:

```
$("#datepicker, #datepicker2").datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true
});
```

Or add a classe and use a selector by class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add id of all the elements you need to add datepicker to, just like below:

```
$("#datepicker,#datepicker2").datepicker({
   showOtherMonths: true,
   selectOtherMonths: true
});
```